# How do I execute commands before shutdown in Windows 7 (and before it kills all running programs?)

Tags: windows-7, automation, virtualbox, shutdown, reboot

I have a batch file that starts a VirtualBox VM when windows starts and I'd like to have one that automatically saves the state of the VM when someone reboots or shuts down the machine.

I can't use GPO because everything it does happens after Windows has killed everything else.

So is there a way to modify how Windows handles this or maybe intercept the shutdown/reboot signal somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution a while ago. It uses python so it is not the most lightweight solution but it worked for me.

> - Download [vbox-shutdown.py](https://gist.github.com/ionelmc/8245494) somewhere there are write permissions (it will create a logfile unless you specify it a different path).
> - Python 2.7 with same architecture as VirtualBox - if you have 64bit system most probably you'll need a 64-bit Python (I've used the COM
>     api - it doesn't allow cross arch interop for now). This could change
>     by using the command line API if anyone really wanted this. Anyone can
>     fix it - it's just some Python code.
> - Install pywin32 - same architecture/reason as above.
> - Install the vboxapi package. Running python vboxapisetup.py install in c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\sdk\install\ did the trick for
>     me. I wonder why they have this useless pypi package with no
>     distributions ...
> - Now just run shell:startup and put the file in there.

**All the credits go to ionelmc** http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/01/04/virtualbox-vm-auto-shutdown/

Comment: @gnat Here you go, theessential is here with credits to the actual problem solver

Answer (score 0):

Ok, best I could come up with

The following python script will wait for a shutdown, abort it, call your script, then restart the shutdown. Add it to start at startup.

**EDIT requires pywin32 python extension availible [Here](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html)**

1 Problem is it won't abort a shutdown from the start menu or power button. Only software shutdowns.  You can disable them like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7553/remove-shutdown-and-restart-buttons-in-windows-7/) and [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000735.htm).  If you still want the ability to manually shutdown your pc, add a batch file **NAMED ANYTHING BUT "SHUTDOWN"** with the following contents

```
shutdown -f -s
```

python script

```
import win32security
import win32api
import sys
import time
from ntsecuritycon import *
import os
import subprocess

Pre_ShutdownScript = "your Script"
Shutdown = True
# Get the process token
flags = TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY
htoken = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), flags)

# Get the ID for the system shutdown privilege.
idd = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME)

while Shutdown:
    try:
        win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0, [(idd, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)])
        win32api.AbortSystemShutdown(None)
        Shutdown = False        
    except:
        win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0, [(idd, 0)])
        time.sleep(1)

try:
    subprocess.call([Pre_ShutdownScript])
except:
    pass
os.system("shutdown -r -t 1")
```

Comment: I had ActivePython 2.7 installed so I added your script, launched it. Now I just have to wait for a software reboot :s
Too bad it doesn't work with the regular shutdown/reboot.

Comment: The shutdown script mentioned above will cause one.

Comment: This does not seem to work...
I used "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe controlvm MyVM savestate" as script. Maybe I should have done it some other way (this command works in cmd.exe)

Comment: This will work on that. I assume the porblem is backward slashes.  You either need to put as the string  "C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe controlvm MyVM savestate"  or  "C:/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe controlvm MyVM savestate"  Also, did you see the edit with regards to the pywin32 extension.  Any errors that show up will also help.  I'm kind of invested now that I spent so much time getting it to work :-)

Comment: Also, copied and pasted the exact text just to make sure. I was missing a pass after the last except.  Updated works correctly.

Comment: I added pywin32, corrected the 2 mistakes in the script (the slashes and the missing pass) but it still doesn't work. Anyhow, it's not what I had in mind at all and doesn't answer my question. Sorry if you spend so much time on this. Instead of using this I can simply use a batch file that will execute my command then shutdown/reboot. Finally, I wanted to KIS

Answer (score 0):

5moufl you stated "I can't use GPO because everything it does happens after Windows has killed everything else". Can you elaborate on the local group policy change you tried? Were there any errors? What didn't work exactly for you? When the VM came up on a subsequent restart what happened?

There are details on defining a shutdown action here as a group policy:
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3358-execute-a-script-a-startup-and-shutdown :

- Start Menu > Run > Type gpedit.msc
- Computer Configuration > Windows
- Settings > Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)
- Double click on Shutdown to bring up the Properties window
- Click Add > Browse to add a shutdown script
- The shutdown BAT script could be:
  "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" controlvm MyVM savestate

Comment: I would have to try again because it was a while ago but when I tried what you said, the VBoxHeadless.exe process had already been killed so there was nothing left (no "state") to save.